# Good techniques for transparent info in game UI

Tags: transparency, interface-design, games

For a game that I am developing, I am trying to include a non-intrusive overlay to help the player understand what keys to use as they progress through the game. I'm looking to design something like this: [image: this]. How is the Wii controller outline created like that?

**Edit**: More specifically, how would make an outline look like the outline of the controller using some sort of tool like photoshop?

Comment: You use opacity. How to do this specifically would require an understanding of how you're building the app and what software you are using, As it is now, this question is simply too broad.

Comment: I'm looking for the general way to approach this. For example, "you would use a combination of technique X with technique Y etc". Also, it's an overlay so I'll design it in a vector graphics application of some sort as opposed to via code. It doesn't need to be generated dynamically.

Comment: "Generally", it's using opacity. It's an object (in this case using white) laid on top of another object and the opacity is then set to something less than 100% (in this case, it looks maybe 60% or so).

Comment: I tried that, but it looks like there's some sort of effect on the outline that makes like the outline gradually fades almost like a gradient of sorts. Sorry, it's hard for me to describe. Make sense or am I seeing things?

Comment: Yes, they are also using gradients, drop shadows, and glow effects.

Comment: Ok. That's what I'm talking about! Would the drop shadow be black? I'm assuming it disappears mostly due to the change in alpha right? If you post your answer I'll select it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I gave it a shot. It does look look like they're using dark shadows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking what kinds of techniques were used for that specific image, it could include:

- outer glows (the white glow around some elements)
- inner glows (the glow inside the controller)
- drop shadows (the shadows beneath the text)
- gradients (the arrows going from light to transparent)
- opacity (the entire thing has an opacity less than 100% an individually elements are layered with various opacity settings)